# jQuery .clone setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a div which contains text/images and a custom jQuery plugin for those images. Basically all the plugin does is animate a fadeIn/fadeOut effect every 3 seconds using setInterval. This div is like the 'cache' div. When a user requests to view this div it loads it into the viewer div using .clone(). However it doesn't copy the timing events, it just copies the current state of the gallery.

I know why this is happening: because the plugin I wrote only applies to the gallery in the cache div and when I clone it it has no way to copy the plugin.

A snippet of the gallery code looks like this:

```
var animateCb = function() {
    if($next_image.length == 0)
        $next_image = $images.filter(":first");
    $curr_image.fadeOut(settings.speed);
    $next_image.fadeIn(settings.speed);
    $curr_image = $next_image;
    $next_image = $curr_image.next();
}
setInterval(animateCb, settings.time);
```

Then theres a div like this:

```
<div class='cache' id='cache-1'>
    <div class='gallery' id='gallery-1'>
            <div class='gallery-item' id='gallery-item-1'><img src='img1.jpg' /></div>         
            <div class='gallery-item' id='gallery-item-2'><img src='img2.jpg' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I apply the gallery plugin using

```
$(".gallery").gallery();
```

And when I want to copy the cache div to the viewing div I use

```
$("#viewing-div").empty();
$("#cache-1").clone(true).appendTo("#viewing-div");
```

Does anyone have a way I could fix this? I don't want to load the gallery plugin when a user requests to view the cache , it needs to already be loaded.

Comment: By the way clone method actually multiplies the elements. I wonder if you do really want to multiply the element or may be you want to move it around?

Comment: setInterval and setTimeOut can be tricky. It's in the way the method calls the next function. Can you post an example of the code?

Comment: Could you give some concrete example, i.e. code? I have a bit trouble to imagine the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.clone(true)` this will preserve the events.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: It does not seem the OP is binding event handlers but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I'm not binding event handlers, I have tried .clone(true).

Comment: Then I can't quite understand what you want. Adding some code might help.